# How to spawn sdf object in Ignition Gazebo?

Tags: ignition-dome

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I spawn a model into a running simulation in Ignition Gazebo?
I'm looking for something like [rosrun gazebo spawn_model](http://wiki.ros.org/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation) but for Ignition.

This was the closest thing I found but I couldn't get it working so far:
https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/issues/27#issuecomment-510046123

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26037/how-to-spawn-sdf-object-in-ignition-gazebo?/) by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You already have the answer in your link above. There is an example in [ros_ign_gazebo_demos](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/blob/melodic/ros_ign_gazebo_demos/launch/create.launch#L14):

```
<node
  pkg="ros_ign_gazebo"
  type="create"
  name="spawn_model"
  args="-world <world_name> -name <model_name> -param robot_description">
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benedikt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/88831/benedikt/) on 2022-09-01**:
Is there a ROS2 Galactic node equivalent to remove an entity? I've  just found a node to create an entity [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/galactic/ros_ign_gazebo).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

you can have a look in the [empty.sdf](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/blob/ign-gazebo4/examples/worlds/empty.sdf) world.

Inserting:

```
ign service -s /world/empty/create \
--reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory \
--reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean \
--timeout 300 \
--req 'sdf: '\
'"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>'\
'<sdf version=\"1.6\">'\
'<model name=\"spawned_model\">'\
'<link name=\"link\">'\
'<visual name=\"visual\">'\
'<geometry><sphere><radius>1.0</radius></sphere></geometry>'\
'</visual>'\
'<collision name=\"visual\">'\
'<geometry><sphere><radius>1.0</radius></sphere></geometry>'\
'</collision>'\
'</link>'\
'</model>'\
'</sdf>" '\
'pose: {position: {z: 10}} '\
'name: "new_name" '\
'allow_renaming: true'
```

Deleting

```
ign service -s /world/empty/remove \
--reqtype ignition.msgs.Entity \
--reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean \
--timeout 300 \
--req 'name: "new_name" type: MODEL'
```

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-02-17**:
Omg...i love you! This is what I need!!! Just like that! God bless you